# 野良のWindowsStoreアプリを配布する方法は

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-10

WindowsStoreアプリ(正式には ユニバーサル Windows プラットフォーム (UWP) アプリ？)
をストアを介さずに配布したいのですが、Windows10Homeで追加料金を払わずに野良のWindowsストアアプリを動かすことは現状も出来ないのでしょうか。

Andoridの様に事前にどこどこの設定を切り替えると、後はアプリのバイナリを実行すると普通にインストールが出来る という機能を望んでいます。

「サイドローディング」という名称らしいのですが、Homeエディションでは無理みたいですし
サイドローディング プロダクト キー という物を使えばHomeでもいけるみたいですが追加の料金が発生してしまいます

参考 https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/jj874388.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10でのサイドローディングは、Technetライブラリのこちらのページが一次的な資料になると思います: [Windows 10 での LOB アプリのサイドローディング (Windows)](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/mt269549.aspx)

私も実際に試したわけではありませんが、以下2つのことは言えると考えています。

- サイドローディングプロダクトキーは廃止されました。追加費用はかかりません。
- 特にエディションについての制限は書かれていないので、Homeでも可能ではないかと考えています。